# Unsure what dimensions of matrices and inputs to use for direct shooting

Tags: drake

I am unsure what dimensions are appropriate for this, and my current implementation is getting dimension errors, so I wanted to post all of my variables here and see which one is incorrect.

[Variable initialization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wlmnB.png)

Here is the cost function (where I am also trying to add in trajectory and I am getting an error). [Cost function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p4wjK.png)

Here are my inputs when I call the function: get_J_star_N_shooting(A, B, Q, R, QN, N, x0)

And here is my error: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ljqq.png)

Comment: FYI -- You got some comments on a previous post about how stackoverflow discourages the use of images for code.  You should post in the code instead.

It's hard to diagnose from these fragments, but I would recommend using `A @ x` instead of `A.dot(x)` for the matrix multiplication.  I think the semantics there make more sense, and might help you find any remaining dimension mismatches.